# The stones of Joshua in Gilgal, are they still there today?

Tags: yehoshua-joshua

([Joshua 7 : 26](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.7.26?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

> And they raised over him a great heap of stones to this day. So the Lord turned from the fierceness of His anger. Therefore, the name of that place was called, The Valley of Achor, **to this day**.

What does it mean to this day ? Is it referring to the day the book was written or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40297/1739

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/40373/9215

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is perfectly clear where it is but perhaps this is the beginning of an answer...

The Valley of Achor is mentioned on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achor)

According to the [Jewish Jericho website](https://www.jewishjericho.org.il/hebrew/places/dvir.html) it writes:

> עמק עכור נזכר גם בגבול שבין שבט יהודה לבנימין. אחרי אבן בוהן בן ראובן ולפני דביר, המזוהה בבית ג'בר א-תחתני, היא החורבה הצמודה לגבול האוטונומיה. מדרומה יש כמין אמפיתיאתרון ענק ובמרכזו גבעה הכניסה אליו היא ממזרח לבית ג'בר א-תחתני
>
> *The Valley of Achor that is mentioned was also on the border between the tribe of Yehuda and Binyamin. It was after the stone of Bohan, the son of Reuven(1) and before the region of Dvir, identified in Bait Jaber A-Tachtani. It is the site bordering the autonomy. To the south there is a giant amphitheater, and in the center there is a hill East to Beit Jabar A-Tachtani.*

---

(1) Refer to [Rashi on Yehoshua 15:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Joshua.15.6?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) for context on the name of the place - click on the footnote 9.